Chrome open a max of 5 tabs only
I often open many tabs (10+) while I work (follow up links, etc). I just switched to a new system (IDEAPAD) running Ubuntu 24.04. When I open up to 5 tabs, Chrome won't open an additional tab. Either I close one, or open the page in an already opened tab (so closing existing page).
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble

Chrome version:
$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 125.0.6422.141 

System info:
$ free -m
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31698        5350       23675        1662        4771       26347
Swap:           8191           0        8191


$ lscpu
Architecture:             x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):         32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:          46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:             Little Endian
CPU(s):                   18
  On-line CPU(s) list:    0-17
Vendor ID:                GenuineIntel
  Model name:             Intel(R) Core(TM) Ultra 5 125H
    CPU family:           6
    Model:                170
    Thread(s) per core:   2
    Core(s) per socket:   14
    Socket(s):            1
    Stepping:             4
    CPU(s) scaling MHz:   20%
    CPU max MHz:          4500.0000
    CPU min MHz:          400.0000
    BogoMIPS:             5990.40
    ...

How do I change this to support open more tabs?
